# Can't resolve all parameters Ioni

Tags: ionic4

When I add ionic storage in my constructor it gives error 'Can't resolve all parameters for ProductPage: ([object Object], ?).'
in app module, I added IonicStorageModule. 
This is my constructor. This code is page.

```
constructor(public service: ApiService, private storage: Storage) {
        this.productData = [];
    }
```

If I remove storage in the constructor app is working.

Comment: Where did you import storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i close and reopen the IDE it's worked.